# Would this recording app idea be feasible to implement in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sorry for the vagueness of the title, but I couldn't fit the whole question in there.

I have this idea for an app, and I have some experience with swift in the past, but I have never used certain features that I would need to in this app. I wanted to ask you guys about those features and see if they would be possible to implement.

The app will have a few simple features. When it detects that a person pulls over while driving, it will start a recording. I will be using google speech to text API to transcribe the recording, just to detect if a conversation is occurring. The app will save the recording on the user's phone, and later the user will have the option to delete the recording if they please.

I imagine that the first challenging part of the app would be the identification of someone pulling over. The thing is, I do not want to start a recording if they park, only if they pull over. Would this be implementable with swift? I have never used a location-based API in swift, so I don't have experience with that.

The second challenge will probably be the recording itself. From what I have read online, recording as a background application is possible. I was mostly wondering, are there any legal implications that would stop the app from being submitted to the app store? Would the recording have to be saved in a specific location, like natively on their phone, or are there any restrictions I should know of when doing this? Also, would the phone automatically turning off stop the app from being able to detect the pulling over and recording?

If the questions are still too vague, please let me know in the comments and I will answer them in more depth.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is probably not.

Only a very small list of app types are allowed to run constantly in the background: VoIP apps, turn-by-turn navigation apps, music player apps, and maybe one or more two that I am forgetting. All others get suspended very quickly if the user switches to another app or locks their phone.

You might need to require that the user keep your app running and in the foreground, and disable the phone from going to sleep on its own. (For that you'd want the phone plugged in to the car's accessory outlet so you don't drain the battery.)

You'd need to ask the user for permission to collect their location info, and would also need permission to access the microphone.

Once you are running constantly you would need to define the difference between pulling over and parking. It isn't clear to me what that difference is. Maybe start recording automatically when the user stops, and discard the recording if you later decide it doesn't meet the definition of "pulling over"